# Seperate subgroups in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, boxplot, kendo-dataviz

I have visualized some data by using boxplots. Each variable belongs to a subgroup and I want to separate/indicate on these subgroups in the boxplot. Either to create a small gap between each 'group of variables' or in some way indicated on the different variable belonging **without** using `fill = type`. Below I've generated some data that can work as an example data.

```
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
value <- sample(20:80, 1000, replace = T)
group <- sample(c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"), 1000, TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(value, group))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value),
         type = ifelse(grepl("*2", group),"Group 2", "Group1"),
         ) 

ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y =group))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlim(0, 100)
```

This gives the following boxplot:

[image]

I tried to subgroup the plot by adding `facet_wrap(~type, dir="v")` which generates the following plot:

[image]

However, I don't know how to remove the empty variables (eg. in Group 2: A1, B2, C3).

Does anyone know how to, in an adequate way, (with `facet_wrap()` or not) on indicating on subgroups of variables in boxplot without using `fill = type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the not used factor levels with `scales = "free"`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
value <- sample(20:80, 1000, replace = T)
group <- sample(c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"), 1000, TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(value, group))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value),
         type = ifelse(grepl("*2", group),"Group 2", "Group1"),
  ) 

ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y =group))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlim(0, 100) +
  facet_wrap(~type, dir="v", scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @starja. That works. Just out of curiosity, do you know if it is possible to do this without either ```fill = type``` or ```facet_wrap(~type, dir = "v", scales = "free")```?

Comment: @ecl so you want only one plot? You could specify the order of the barplots with setting the factor levels, but I think then it's a bit difficult to introduce a gap to distinguish the groups. Maybe the easier solution is to change the `facet_wrap` appearance